# How to properly send a response from an express server to the client

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to fetch data from my mongoDB collection and send it back to the client in a response and for some reason the json I get as a response is always empty:

```
app.get("/users", bodyparser.json(), function(req, res) {
  collection.find().toArray().then(dbresponse => {
    console.log(dbresponse)
    res.json(dbresponse);
    console.log(res.json)
  })
})
```

the dbresponse has all of the data I am looking to get, but res.json() doesn't seem to be writing anything to the response,

The client side looks like this:

```
  fetch("/users")
    .then(res => res.json)
    .then(json => {
      console.log(json)
      Array.from(json).forEach(user => addUser(user.user, user.pass, user.id))
    })
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client code should be `fetch("/users").then(res => res.json())`.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Oh man, thanks, I've been struggling for an hour haha